# What's the type of a blob?

Tags: ajax, blob

I'm making a website with codeigniter. I'm trying to upload a blob via ajax. It's an audio wav file. In the config I need the allowable types for the upload files. What should this be for a blob?

`$config['allowed_types'] =` ...?

Thanks!

Comment: In regards to which language/tools?

Comment: We are using codeigniter to make our website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the content-type?  It's whatever you set it to client-side when preparing the request.

Comment: You are right. I found out that my upload did not accept mime-types which my blob is so that's what my problem really was. Thanks